# Airflow does not reflect status of GCP Cloud Run job once complete

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, http-status-codes

I have an Airflow DAG (GCP Composer) that invokes a Cloud Run job using HTTPS POST.

I am using a PythonOperator to invoke the Cloud Run job as follows:

```
run_report_task = PythonOperator(
  python_callable=invoke_with_http,
        task_id="run_report",
        dag=dag,
        op_kwargs={
            "method": "POST",
            "service_name": f"my-report-{ENV}",
            "json": {
                "date": DATE,
                "env": ENV
            }
        }
    )
```

The `invoke_with_http` method invokes the Cloud Run job successfully, however once the job completes it does not return the status code to the DAG.

As a result the Airflow DAG continues with "Running" status until marked as "Success" manually.

**How do I return the status of the cloud run job to composer and set the task status to reflect the job outcome?**

I have tried returning "OK" from the cloud run job main function that is annotated with `@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])`

Comment: do you have job_id and api to get status ? in that case you get use HttpSensor to check the job_id status untill it is completed.

Comment: Are you sure this problem is related to [tag:composer-php]?

Comment: @NicoHaase typo - have updated the tags!